# Remove first character of every word

Tags: notepad++

How to remove first character of every string in notepad++

i have:

```
0x61, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x31, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x5C, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x66,
```

i want to remove **0** before every **x** on every line.
so it would like:

```
x61, x6E, x67, x31, x30, x33, x33, x5C, x64, x65, x66, x6C, x61, x6E, x67, x66,
```

how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `0x`
- Replace with: `x`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: oh, It was so easy, and my brain did not know where it was gone, i was searching for regex Instead of simple find and replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Find String " 0" (space and 0) and replace with " " space.

Comment: This will change `0x30` into `x3`